# ngOninit hook of AppComponent is not being called on Page refresh

Tags: angular, typescript

I navigated to `/posts` (`localhost:4200/posts`), but when I refresh the page `ngOnInit()` of `AppComponent` is not being called.

Comment: Can you recreate the problem in a stackblitz? And adding your code to your question might help others recreate the problem.

Comment: where is your router-outlet. Do you even display AppComponent inside a router-outlet?

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

export class App implements OnInit {
  constructor() {
     // Called first time before the ngOnInit()
  }

  ngOnInit() {
     // Called after the constructor and called  after the first ngOnChanges() 
  }
}
is this the same way you have implemented in your project?
```

Comment: yes its the same way I implemented it. but I am surprised to see that ngOninit is not being called When page reloads

Comment: can you try calling that service inside constructor itself?